# Earliest occurrences of meditation?

Tags: meditation-practicalities, history

What are the earliest records of people meditating?

The Wiki page for History of meditation mentions "prehistory" but provides no details:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_meditation

The only other mentions begin at around 1500 BC.

Comment: Note that "[prehistory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recorded_history#Prehistory)" is (or means), by definition, "earlier than the earliest written records".

Comment: Maybe that's why the section provides no details :) Anyone know of evidence that would suggest early meditative practice?

Comment: Other sites where you could try asking a question like this include Hinduism.SE or History.SE.

Comment: Did you lookup "harappa" or "indus-culture"? If I remember correctly there are small statues showing some Shiva-like figure sitting in Lotus-position. And the Harappa-culture has been a very early one in the Indus-valley, may be earlier than 1500 BCE

Comment: In the wikipedia at "indus valley culture" there is the following remark: *Seals have been found at Mohenjo-Daro depicting a figure standing on its head, and another sitting cross-legged in what some call a yoga-like pose (see image, the so-called Pashupati, below).* 
*This figure, sometimes known as a Pashupati, has been variously identified. Sir John Marshall identified a resemblance to the Hindu god, Shiva.[68] If this can be validated, it would be evidence that some aspects of Hinduism predate the earliest texts, the Veda.*

Comment: Shiva is not mentioned in the Pali suttas, where Brahma, Indra & Prajapati are mentioned. Wiki states Shiva is absent in the Vedas (the Brahman texts when Buddha was alive). Aboriginal people in Australia traditionally sat cross legged.

Answer (score 1):

According to various internet sources, 5000 years ago, or approximately 3000 BC, references to the form of mediation used at the time is found in Hindu scriptures. 
According to Lovetoknow.com, A recent archaeological find in the then capital city of Moheyo-dara, capital city of the Indus Valley civilization, by John Marshall of a seal of a meditating yogi is dated at 2600 BC approximately. Of course , it may be assumed that meditation was taking place for an indefinite period of time prior.

Answer (score 1):

In the Indian tradition the earliest appearance of meditation seems to be during the Indus Valley period (3300-1300 BCE) in the form of a bronze seal possibly depicting an early form of Shiva (Pashupati), seated in cross-legged pose with an obvious erection. It was found in Mohenjo-Daro, dated at about 2500 BCE. The figure is also surrounded by animals, and has been associated with the archetype of the Lord of the Animals (a.k.a. the Theriomorphic Ancestor).